# PHP Email Not Sending

Tags: php, email

I have this script which i use on my own website:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$email_subject = "New Customer Registration AP-Photography";
$from = "registrations@aftab-photography.dpwebdev.co.uk";
$email_to = "david@dpwebdev.co.uk";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message2 = "Hello! This is a automatic email message.";
    $email_message2 .= "<BR>";
    $email_message2 .= "<BR>";
    $email_message2 .= "A New User has registered on aftab-photography.co.uk.";
    $email_message2 .= "<BR>";
    $email_message2 .= "<BR>";
    $email_message2 .= '<td width="6%">Name:</td><td width="34%">'.clean_string($user_id).'</td>';
    $email_message2 .= "<BR>";
    $email_message2 .= "<BR>";
    $email_message2 .= "Thanks";
    $email_message2 .= "<BR>";
    $email_message2 .= "Aftab-Photography";


$emailfrom = $from;
$emailto = "ap_photography@hotmail.co.uk";
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$emailfrom."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$emailto."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message2, $headers);

echo "Mail Sent";
}
?>
```

This is used to email me when a customer registers on my website however it doesn't email me at all.

Any ideas?

David

BTW: I have a linux server with default installation.

Comment: `@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message2, $headers);` can you remove **@** and add error to question pls.

Comment: Rather than actually going through that code, I'm just going to say **[SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)**.

Comment: First off, have you tested this with a simplified message body? Secondly, have you checked your spam folder?

Comment: no errors when i remove the @

Comment: yes both neither enlighten me

Comment: I'm positive there's a duplicate here somewhere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+email. Obligatory "Try a library like Swiftmailer, PHPmailer, etc"

Comment: why you have @ sign before mail method? check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) here.

Comment: @DavidPassmore -- Are you sure your `from` address is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the return value from mail().  If it is false, then there was a problem sending the mail.  If true, then the mail was sent correctly and the problem would probably be in the mail address.

Check your php.ini to see what your default mailer program is, and how it is configured.

Check the mailer logs to see if the message is being queued/delivered correctly.

Answer (score -1):

This variable:

`$from = "registrations@aftab-photography.dpwebdev.co.uk";`

cannot be this it has to be this:

`$from = "registrations@aftab-photography.co.uk";`

Comment: You can have email accounts under subdomains, so you're wrong on this one.

Comment: well unfortunately you could be right, but i change this and it works.

Comment: OK. Since it worked I gave you a + instead of -. Though it's odd behavior, perhaps a PHP bug, or perhaps your server's settings don't allow email account under subdomains.